# C# Devexpress and XPO How do I filter a listview

Tags: c#, filter, devexpress, xpo, xaf

I have a Agency class that contains an xpcollection of Agent.
There is a list of Agencies in the system.
The Agent class contains a reference to the id of the Agency class.
The Agent class derives from SecuritySystemUser and is used to log on to the system.

When I select the select the Agency navigation item, I want to only display the agents that belongs to the same Agency that the logged on user (read Agent) belongs to.

Can someone please provide the filter code or how to set it up in the Business Object designer

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress Support Team directly?

Answer (score 1):

In XAF applications, there are two basic approaches to achieve your desired filtering requirements:

- use the 'New' security [documented here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument3366) and use an 'Read' object permission (as you suggest) with criteria something like `Agent.Agency = CurrentUserAgency()` where `CurrentUserAgency()` would be a [custom function criteria operator](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument3307)
- handle the filtering with ViewControllers [using the method described here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2652) which has the advantage of working with the older (pre 11.2) security system as well.

The first method is preferable, but the second method gives you more control and might be better if your rules to determine which agencies should appear are complex.

You can find [a sample project here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4045) which demonstrates a similar scenario.

As with all things DevExpress, your best avenue for answers is their [support center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).

Answer (score 0):

Check filter lookup on Devexpress XAF

or Click here for more info
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xaf/CustomDocument2755